# What is chrome-extension:// installHook.js that is being downloaded for my pages

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have been creating a couple of webpages using three.js recently. When I inspect what's being downloaded in Chrome I see a file named installHook.js. I have searched here on SO and other corners of the internet but can't find out what it is (possibly it is linked to React but I don't use that). Does anyone know what it is and if I can somehow remove it as it is the largest resource being downloaded?

[image: Pic showing downloaded resources in Chrome]

If I follow the link I get to this file
[image: Pic showing downloaded resources in Chrome]

[image: Pic showing downloaded resources in Chrome]

Strange thing is that I see this both for sites using web pack and sites who don´t.

Comment: This is not really a three.js issue. That script could be coming from anywhere, and your network tab says the initiator is `prepareInjection.js`. Try clicking on that link to see where it's coming from. I would start by disabling one `<script>` at a time until it's no longer getting downloaded to find the culprit.

Comment: @Marquizzo Yes, I did not think it was three.js, I just added it as extra information in case it was a known fact. I will try to disable the scripts as you suggested.

Comment: Is this happening in a Webpack dev environment? If so, then you shouldn’t worry about it. Webpack adds a bunch of scripts to help with fast development, like hot-module replacement, but they should all go away once you deploy the final production build.

Comment: I thought it was related to Webpack (which now use) but when I check a previous site I created, at a time when I did not even know about webpack, it shows the same file :). It does not show up in the network tab in Firefox or Safari.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my case, installHook.js comes from the React Dev Tools Chrome extension. You don't need to worry about this as it does not affect the performance of the application for end users.

[Screenshot: some code of the installHook.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5FxL.png)

Comment: Aha, that seems to be the case. I have removed all extensions since i asked the question and when i check the same page now installHook.js is no longer downloaded. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer is great, but I wanted to add more detail in case your browser is loading other files you don't recognize, from extensions *other than* "React Dev Tools".

In the network tab (OP posted a screenshot) you can click on the request to see the details of the request.

Note the URL specifically uses a `chrome-extension` protocol, that's our hint that it's a Chrome extension:

`chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/installHook.js`

[image: Chrome dev tools, Network tab, details for a request to installHook.js shows that the request was sent to the URL 'chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/installHook.js']

Note the identifier from the previous URL: "fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi". How can you know **which Chrome extension** the identifier refers to?

Copy the identifier to your clipboard. Visit `chrome://extensions/` in your Chrome browser, and paste the identifier into the search input at the top of the page. You'll notice the search results are filtered to show you *which* extension is loading that file.

[image: a screenshot showing the chrome://extensions page loaded in a Chrome browser, and the search bar at the top is filled with the identifier "fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi" (found in the URL from previous screenshot: 'chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/installHook.js'), the chrome://extensions the search results are filtered to show only the extension matching that identifier; in this case, the React Developer Tools extension]

You can disable the extension by toggling its slider, or remove the extension by clicking the "Remove" button.

If you click the "Detail" button on a particular extension in the `chrome://extensions` window, Chrome should load a specific details page reiterating the identifier. In this case, Chrome loads the URL:

`chrome://extensions/?id=fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi`

... notice the identifier "fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi" appears again.

[image: screenshot of the window when user visits chrome://extensions and clicks the "Detail" button for a specific extension, (in this example, the "React Developer Tools" extension; the URL changes to include the identifier of that extension "chrome://extensions/?id=fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi"]

Note other ways to disable extensions, like [running Chrome with extensions disabled](https://superuser.com/questions/254579/how-to-open-google-chrome-with-extensions-disabled-turned-off) with `--disable-extensions` or `--incognito` flag

Answer (score 1):

That is React Developers tools and you can hide those like this :

[image]